Проверка на целочисленность числа в С++
только начал изучать С++ и возник вопрос. Программа заполняет массив случайными числами, N - количество элементов массива. Необходимо проверить его на несколько параметров, проблема с проверкой введенного пользователем числа на целочисленность, проверка на тот случай, если пользователь введет с клавиатуры не целое число, например 2.2. Пытался несколькими способами -
if (typeid(N) != typeid(int)) 
 { 
  cout << "Количество элементов массива должно быть целым числом." << endl; 
  return 1; 
 
 }

или
switch(N)
    {
        case sizeof(N) != 4:
            cout << "введите целое число элементов массива";
        break;
    }

Однако корректно программа не работает, то переменные типа float не проходят проверку, то при вводе подходящего числа не составляется массив(например при вводе 2: вывод "Количество элементов массива должно быть целым числом), не могу найти проблему, помогите пожалуйста.
весь код:
#include <iostream> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <ctime> 
#include <typeinfo> 
 
using namespace std; 
int main() 
{ 
 setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus"); // для корректного вывода русского языка 
 long N; // количество элементов массива 
 float* pt; // используется для доступа к элементам массива A по адресу, а не по индексу 
 srand(time(NULL)); 
 
 cout << "введите четное количество символов "; 
 
 cin >> N; // ввод числа 
 

 
 
 if (typeid(N) != typeid(int)) 
 { 
  cout << "Количество элементов массива должно быть целым числом." << endl; 
  return 1; 
 
 } 
  
 else if (N == 0) 
 { 
  cout << "количество элементов массива не может быть равно нулю \n "; 
  return 1; 
   
 } 
 else if (N < 0) 
 { 
  cout << "количество элементов массива не может быть отрицательным \n "; 
  return 1; 
   
 } 
  
 else if (N % 2 != 0) 
 { 
  cout << "количество элементов массива должно быть четным \n "; 
  return 1; 
   
 } 
 
 float* A = new float[N]; //  оператор new для динамического выделения памяти под массив элементов типа float 
  
 
 cout << "первоначальный массив \n"; 
 
 for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
 { 
   
  A[i] = (float)rand() / RAND_MAX; // заполнение массива случайными числами 
  cout <<  *(A + i) << endl; // вывод массива 
 } 
 
 pt = A; // присваивает указателю pt адрес начала массива A 
 
 for (int i = 0; i < N; i+=2) // цикл с шагом 2, для того, чтобы поменять местами каждую пару в массиве 
 { 
  float perv = *(pt + i); // временная переменная, в которую сохраняется значение первого элемента массива из пары 
  *(pt + i) = *(pt + i + 1); // первому элементу из двойки присваивается следующий элемент(меняет местами) 
  *(pt + i + 1) = perv; // присваиваем второму элементу из двойки значение первого 
 } 
 cout << "массив с условием \n"; 
 
 for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
 { 
  cout << *(pt + i) << endl; // вывод массива с условием 
 } 
}


long N это всегда целое число, по-другому быть не может

Для начала. Переменная N у вас объявлена как long N;, т.е. она целого типа и ничего проверять с ней не надо. На мой взгляд проще всего проверит целочисленность значения переменной с плавающей точкой это сравнить floor и ceil о него (if (floor(x) == ceil(x)) // целое)

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask //также typeid(N) вернёт тип переменной, а не введённые данные, поэтому проверку на целостность не пройдет

Вы спрашиваете не как забить гвоздь, а в какой руке держать микроскоп, забивая им гвозди. Давайте начнем с изначального задания, которое вам надо решить, а не с выяснения, целочисленное ли у вас число в целочисленной переменной... Как формулируется ваше задание? Судя по всему, ответ на то, что вы хотите спросить, можно найти, например, здесь...

Подозреваю, что подразумевалась проверка на случай, если кто-то введет с клавиатуры не целое число, например 3.4. Однако cin >> N; не меняет тип N, вместо этого разбор целого числа в перегруженном операторе >> остановится на точке.

Спасибо, что поняли и объяснили, уже внес изменения в запрос. Извините, как же мне все-таки проверять N на цифры после запятой, чтобы программа не брала только целую часть введенного числа и не составляла массив? Честно не понимаю, с  (if (floor(x) == ceil(x)) проверку число не проходит. Явно делаю что-то не то.

В N никаких цифр после запятой быть не может, так как эта переменная имеет целочисленный тип. И массива никакого нет. А то, что в стандартном вводе не осталось какого-то мусора можно проверить, прочитав оттуда один char, если все правильно, то тамбудет символ переноса строки. Еще у стандартного потока ввода есть всякие флаги ошибок, типа fail() или bad(), которые следует проверять.

Рассматриваем случай, когда число считывается из консоли по нажатию Enter. В cin >> N; перегруженный оператор >> сначала пропускает пробельные символы (при наличии), затем пытается читать цифры целого числа, пока не случится переполнение, либо пока он не наткнется на символ, отличный от цифры.
Если после пробельных символов поток встретит не цифру, а что-то другое (ввод G), и в случае переполнения (ввод 23333333333333333333333) чтение останавливается и у потока будет выставлен флаг состояния fail. Отсутствие этого флага следует сразу проверить явным вызовом функции if (not cin.fail()), либо if (cin.good()), либо через оператор приведения к bool if (cin) (что является более лаконичным эквивалентом вызова good).
Если после чтения нескольких цифр поток наткнется на первый не числовой символ (ввод 1.3), то чтение останавливается и никакой ошибки не возникает. Для проверки отсутствия остановки из-за встретившегося мусора следует достать из потока один символ - если это символ окончания строки, то все ОК.
В случае неуспешного чтения следует сбросить флаги состояния и пропустить оставшийся кусок строки. И не забыть проверить достижение конца потока (особенно полезно при перенаправлении стандартного ввода из файла).
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int inint()
{
    int result{};
    for (;;)
    {
        ::std::cout << "Input integer: " << ::std::flush;
        if ((::std::cin >> result) and ('\n' == ::std::cin.get()))
        {
            break;
        }
        // сброс состояния ошибок потока
        ::std::cin.clear();
        // пропуск мусора до символа переноса строки (включительно)
        ::std::cin.ignore(::std::numeric_limits<::std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        // проверка достижения конца потока
        if (::std::cin.eof())
        {
            ::std::cout << "End of input." << ::std::endl;
            ::std::exit(1);
        }
        ::std::cout << "Bad input, repeat." << ::std::endl;
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    auto const x{inint()};
    ::std::cout << "got " << x << ::std::endl;
    auto const x2{inint()};
    std::cout << "got " << x2 << ::std::endl;
    auto const x3{inint()};
    ::std::cout << "got " << x3 << ::std::endl;
}


online compiler
Обратите внимание: на конце последней строки нет символа переноса строки.

G
23333333333333333333333
1.3
1
2
3


Input integer: Bad input, repeat.
Input integer: Bad input, repeat.
Input integer: Bad input, repeat.
Input integer: got 1
Input integer: got 2
Input integer: End of input.


А можно и просто прочесть в string, взять оттуда число, вызвав strtol и проверить следующий за цифрами символ через устанавливаемый этой функцией указатель

@avp ¿Ага, по сравнению с моим ответом помимо операции чтения и проверки следующего за цифрами символа предлагаете еще добавить переменную-строку и читать в нее, и еще переменную-указатель для strtol и еще обработку ошибок этой strtol? Упрощение по всем фронтам, ничего не скажешь.

Неужели вы не поняли, что с вводом, кроме проверки eof ничего делать не надо (т.е. почти весь этот код можно выбросить) А strtol можно натравить на внутренности string.

@avp ¿clear и ignore выбросить? ¿И заменить это портянкой с натравливанием strtol на строку? Никудышный из вас советчик. И если бы это реально было проще, то вы бы предоставили ответ, содержащий [mcve], а не брехали в комментариях.

Конечно, выбросить. Объясняю еще раз. Если внимательно посмотреть на организацию входных данных  как в этом вопросе, то надо просто  прочесть целую строку (съедая '\n') и взять число N из нее. Поэтому никаких проверок кроме EOF не требуется (и никакие clear с ignore тут будут не нужны). Если там не правильно отформатированное целое число, то выдать сообщение об этом и повторить тот же ввод в цикле

Вот так:
Берём строку и сравниваем её с таблицей символов ACSII(У вас русская локаль, так что там возможно будет немного иначе)

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main ()
{
{
    int a = 0;
    std::string b = {};
  try{
      std::cin >> b;
      for(char c: b){
          if(not((int(c) > 46 && int(c) < 58))){
            std::cout << "error";
            return 1;
          }
          else{
              a = std::stoi(b);
          }
      }
  }
  catch(...){
      std::cout << "error";
  }
  std::cout << "Hello, " << a << "!\n";
}


пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
