Как корректно проверить ввод на соответствие типу переменной?
В моей программе подразумевается проверка ввода на соответствие типу int, но при "ошибочном" вводе цикл крутится бесконечно и не даёт ввести новое значение:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

const int arr_size = 5;

using namespace std;

void fill_array(int arr[], int size);
void show_array(const int arr[], int size);
void revalue_array(int arr[], int size, float koef);

int main(void)
{
    int arri[5];
    fill_array(arri, arr_size);

    return 0;
}

void fill_array(int arr[], int size)
{
    int cost;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter " << i + 1<< "st" << " cost: ";
        while (!(cin >> cost))
        {
            cin.clear();
            cout << "Bad input, please, enter a numder: ";
            cin >> cost;
            cout << endl;
            cout << cost << endl;
        }
        
    }
}

Можете, пожалуйста, объяснить причину некорректного поведения моей программы и сказать, что нужно сделать, чтобы она работала правильно?

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1595976/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%A1/1596007#1596007

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1134218/195342

Ошибка в том, что cin.clear() только очистит флаг ошибки, а ошибочное значение так и останется в буфере потока. Это значение можно "съесть" при помощи функции getline().
Исправленный код будет таким:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

const int arr_size = 5;

using namespace std;

void fill_array(int arr[], int size);
void show_array(const int arr[], int size);
void revalue_array(int arr[], int size, float koef);

int main(void)
{
    int arri[5];
    fill_array(arri, arr_size);

    return 0;
}

void fill_array(int arr[], int size)
{
    int cost;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter " << i + 1<< "st" << " cost: ";
    
        cin >> cost;
        while (cin.fail())
        {
            string str;
            cin.clear();
            getline(cin, str, '\n');
            cout << "Bad input, please, enter a numder: ";
            cin >> cost;
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}


Не в тему вообще

AMIACK, вы слишком кардинально меняете вопрос - с "как проверить, что вводится int" на "что мне сделать с моей, чтобы она работала". Мой первый ответ мог вам подсказать направление поиска ответа - проверка состояния флагов потока, сброс флагов ошибки и, наконец, очистка буфера потока ввода.

У меня и в изначальном коде был цикл, который не позволял ввести неправильное значение, и до правильного ответа то-есть int не переходил на следующую итерацию for, но цикл у меня крутится бесконечно. Возможно вы не смотрели или не запускали код, но мой вопрос хоть и некорректно, но довольно отчетливо относился к циклу while, в коем и была проблема. Не просто же так я прикреплял вам код...

Спасибо за поясненение!
